# Setup and Deployment on Visual Studio: Subject and Title Property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I'm got about 4 apps in my workplace that I maintain for our company. I just finished building another one, and I noticed that the Installer interface that Setup and Deployment uses always displays the text in the `[ProductName]` in the Installer's `.Text` field and in the top panel.

There are two other names in the *Setup and Deployment* project's Properties that do not appear to show up anywhere:

- `[Subject]` and
- `[Title]`.

I've tried setting these two fields to different things to see where they might creep up, but I simply can not find the text that I place in them.

So, what are these two fields used for?

FYI: I am not looking for answers like `[Subject]` *Specifies additional information describing an application or component* or `[Title]` *Specifies the title of an installer*. - though, one would think that the `[Title]` property would be the top bar on the actual Installer Dialog - it is **not**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Title property and Subject property are displayed on the Summary page of the Properties dialog box when an installer file (.msi) is selected in the Windows Explorer.

i.e.: Right click the installer and select Properties and switch to the Summary tab.